# experimenting with loop for an OS module

Tags: javascript

```
while(1){

   document.write("<br><br><br><br>"+"keep doings is tough....");
   continue;
}
```

why theses Codes won't output anything at my end

well the code is too simple i can't narrow down further

Answer (score 1):

Since the while loop is infinite there is no point where the [main event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) is free, so there is no repaint of the viewport.

Don't use infinite while loops.

Comment: but js is imperative there is no main it's all interpreted, but are you saying there's no document.write unless there's some logics handling the forever loop then i think that's good info

Comment: @UforUfor — You're [completely wrong](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).